# SQL join tables, total spent by all customers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a newbie at SQL and this is the question I've been struggling with:

I have these tables:

customers(custID, firstname, familyname)

items(itemID, unitcost)

lineitems(quantity, orderID, itemID)

orders(orderID, custID, date)

I need to find the names and total spend of all customers that made more than one order.

```
SELECT SUM(items.unitcost*lineitems.quantity) AS "total_spent"
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers
ON orders.custID=customers.custID
GROUP BY firstname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT orderID)>1
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or MS SQL Server? You've tagged both, but you're not using MS SQL Server syntax.

Comment: It's MySQL. My apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to continue your `joins`:

```
SELECT c.custId, c.firstname, SUM(i.unitcost*li.quantity) total_spent
FROM customers c
    JOIN orders o ON c.custId = o.custId
    JOIN lineitems li ON o.orderId = li.orderId
    JOIN items i ON li.itemId = i.itemId
GROUP BY c.custId, c.firstname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderID)>1
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: having is needed as condition is >1 not >=1

Comment: @Rajesh -- good point, I noticed as I was rereading.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This does it indeed! Thank you so much! Could you please explain to me though why I need so many JOIN statements?

Comment: @gpargian -- you need to `join` to the lineitmes and items tables so you can sum on their amounts.  this might be helpful -- just read up on using `joins` -- http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/